# Is it possible to sync any other folder without desktop, documents, pictures on onedrive?

Tags: sync, onedrive, cloud-storage, online-backup

I am using windows 10 as my operating system. I have a microsoft account which is added to this pc. Only desktop, documents and pictures folder can sync with onedrive. How can I sync other folders with onedrive? Please help me.

Comment: Please move folders you want to sync into “%Userprofile%\Onedrive”, and move out the folders you do not want to sync.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I was not a fan of the userprofile folders, when I used windows 7 in the past. But now Microsoft has OneDrive and it keeps a sync between user profile folders and cloud. So I love them now. It is possible to sync more folders there.

A symbolic link can be created between the folder and one drive destination. First open command prompt, then run the command `mklink /j "%Userprofile%\Onedrive\Destination Folder name" "Full path of source folder"`. Now whenever you will create folders in source will be also synced in one drive when you connect to the internet. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes.  Move the documents in the One Drive folder that you do not want sync'd to another, different folder.  Leave the documents you do want sync'd in the One Drive folder.

Move other folders you do want sync'c into the One Drive main folder.

It may help your thinking to give One Drive folder different names so you can distinguish.

I have different folders in my One Drive "Library" than in my Documents "Library"  .

I use both Drop Box and One Drive and the ideas above service me well.